how change the MARKDOWNX_MEDIA_PATH in Django setting to include the image name in the path?
I am using the markdown library, i want to change the path to the images in a way that it contains the name of the file, according to the markdown [doc][1] the path can change by adding  something like :
from datetime import datetime

MARKDOWNX_MEDIA_PATH = datetime.now().strftime("markdownx/%Y/%m/%d")

i tried adding image.name but it didn't work in the setting now i was wondering if i can inject the
file name here in the setting some how?
